# Access SQL: Not Equals on Null Text Field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this bit of code:

```
UPDATE NewMaster SET NewMaster.[Risk Mitigation Status] = "Pending Audit/Assist"
WHERE (NOT (NewMaster.[Risk Mitigation Status] = "Complete"));
```

This updates all rows to "Complete", except "Pending Audit/Assist" (expected) and NULLs (for me, completely unexpected!)  Same with <> operator.  Do I just need to add OR IS NULL?  This makes no sense to me!

Comment: NULL is NOT "Complete", so I think that makes sense. You just need to add OR IS NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NULLs are tricky like that. You have to explicitly test for, or otherwise escape, them. Trying to compare, convert or otherwise use them together with any non-null value will pretty much always break something.

I'm not practised with Access SQL, but based on [this documentation](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c), it looks like the proper function for escaping them in Access SQL is 'Nz'. As in:

```
WHERE (NOT (Nz(NewMaster.[Risk Mitigation Status],"0") = "Complete"));
```

That will substitute the value "0" for any nulls it finds, before comparing them to the string "Complete".